# Kafka connect (Single message transform) row filtering

Tags: filter, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I read about Kafka connect transformations introduced in kafka 0.10.2.1
https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect_transforms

I noticed that all the transformations are column based transformations.
I have a use-case where I need value based filtering. For example:

consider the following dataset of a group of people:

```
{"firstName": "FirstName1", "lastName": "LastName1", "age": 30}
{"firstName": "FirstName2", "lastName": "LastName2", "age": 30}
{"firstName": "FirstName3", "lastName": "LastName1", "age": 60}
{"firstName": "FirstName4", "lastName": "LastName2", "age": 60}
```

I want my worker to filter all those records whose lastName is LastName2

Is it possible using kafka-connect or I need to write a separate program for this use-case.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No reason why you couldn't solve this with Single Message Transforms - but you'd need to write a custom one since what you're describing is not available through the transforms currently shipped.

This is a useful talk here on when to use, and not to use, SMTs: [Kafka Summit New York 2017 : Single Message Transformations Are Not the Transformations You’re Looking For (Ewen Cheslack-Postava, Confluent)](https://www.confluent.io/kafka-summit-nyc17/resource/)

---

*Edit April 2020*: There is now a [Filter SMT](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/filter.html#filter) provided as part of Confluent Platform

Comment: Did the same. I wrote a Row filter transformation which did the task for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's a ready-to-use [filtering SMT](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.2/configuration/filtering.html) coming with Debezium 1.2. It allows to use any JSR 223 compatible scripting language for filtering out records, e.g. like so:

```
transforms=filter
transforms.filter.type=io.debezium.transforms.Filter
transforms.filter.language=jsr223.graal.js
transforms.filter.condition=value.lastName == 'LastName2'
```

Note while it's part of Debezium, you can use that SMT separately if you want.

Comment: is there any example of how to add the groovy engine to the classpash according to the docs ? i can't find how to it

Comment: You only need to add the Groovy JAR(s) to your connector's directory on the plug-in path of Kafka Connect.

Comment: Hi, can you share steps to implement a similar filter in Kafka-connect? I have a kafka-connect setup which is pushing data from kafka topic to S3.

Comment: The Debezium SMT is based on Kafka Connect, so I'm not quite clear on what you're asking.