# Filtering rows of database

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I would like to know if kafka platform is suitable for the following job.

I'm trying to ingest a full database with multiple tables. Once ingested by Kafka, I would like to filter rows of tables based on condition.

I think that is an easy job to do using Kafka streams, but what happen to messages that are rejected by the filter ?

Conditions could be met in the future if based on a date for example, so will there be a chance that a rejected message be filtered again to eventually pass the filter and be further processed ?

Is it better to filter the rows of data before feeding Kafka with it ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider using a database connector such as Debezium or the Confluent JDBC Source Connector which are both based on Kafka Connect

More on Debezium connector for MySQL see http://debezium.io/docs/connectors/mysql

More on Confluent JDBC Connector see http://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/source_connector.html

With connectors based on Kafka Connect you can filter the rows of data before publishing to Kafka using the Single Message Transform (SMT) feature in Kafka Connect.

See discussion on Row Filtering with Kafka Connect here [Kafka connect (Single message transform) row filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44426711/kafka-connect-single-message-transform-row-filtering)