# Selective transfer of data with Debezium

Tags: oracle, microservices, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

Because my Oracle database has too much data I can't transfer through Debezium without breaking the response time of the old system. Is it possible to do this in batches created according to a certain criteria. I wonder if the following scenario using Debezium is possible.

1. I do **not** transfer all the data from the tables, but only those that meet a certain
   criterion in pseudo code `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE ...`. At this first phase I
   will choose the ones that change with the least intensity.
2. After a certain time, I have decided to redirect the HTTP requests for this data to the new microservice.
3. After bug fixing and code tuning I "loosen" the limits and include more data for
   Debezium to transfer. But again not all data `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE ... OR ...`.

And so until I include all the data from the tables that interest me `SELECT * FROM table_name`.

Do you think such an incremental approach is possible? I'm not so familiar how Debezium choose what to send to Kafka. Can you point me to another, gentler method of breaking the monolith in batches? Any links to such technics will be also helpful.

Comment: Just to clarify I would like to use log based CDC. I suppose filter should happen in transform phase but this is just a guess and I'm not sure how effective it will be

Comment: It is possible using SMT. There is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44426711/kafka-connect-single-message-transform-row-filtering) for that. But is it a good strategy?